# SQL INSERT INTO statement for MS Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-insert, oledbexception

I am trying to learn how to use MS Access with my VB.net program.  I am practicing learning how to use the INSERT INTO statement but I keep getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim DBpath As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\nordeen1\Desktop\Test.mdb"
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBpath & ";Persist Security Info=True"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim SQLstr As String
    SQLstr = "INSERT INTO Test (Text, [Date], Number) VALUES ('testing', #2/6/1990#, 5)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, myConnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
End Class
```

I get this error "OleDbException was unhandled.  Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEXT` and `NUMBER` are also reserved so they should be delimited,

```
SQLstr = "INSERT INTO Test ([Text], [Date], [Number]) VALUES ('testing', #2/6/1990#, 5)"
```

- [MS ACCESS Reserved Keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

Comment: That worked!  I will be accepting this as my answer.  It is possible to pass through variables in the Values section?

Comment: @nordeen1 yes, parameterized the values. Read some about `OleDbCommand`.`Parameters`

Answer (score 2):

Use `CDATE` for your Date :

```
   "INSERT INTO Test ([Text], [Date], [Number]) 
              VALUES ('testing',  CDATE('1990-06-02 00:00:00'), 5)"
```